# I want to display Accounts & its Related Opportunities of a currently login Community User on VF page

Tags: visualforce

Does anyone know how to get the currently logged in community User Accounts & related opportunitites.

My Controller :

```
public class AccountOpportunity {

    public String userid{get;set;}


    public AccountOpportunity (){
    userid = Userinfo.getUserId();

        fetchData();
    }

    public void fetchData(){

       List<Opportunity> op = [Select name,Id,AccountId,Amount from Opportunity ];
        //Parent Id set
        Set<id> parentIdSet = new Set<id>();
        //Create parent Id set 
        for(Opportunity OppRec :op){
            parentIdSet.add(OppRec.AccountId);
        }

        //Fetch all associated parents

        ID contactId = [Select contactid from User where id =: Userinfo.getUserid()].contactId;

        ID AccID  = [Select AccountID from Contact where id =: contactid ].AccountId;

        List<Account> allAssocaiatedAccounts = [Select name,id,AnnualRevenue,Industry from Account where Id IN : parentIdSet ];

        wrapperList = new list<myWrapperClass>();
        //For loop to set data
        for(Opportunity childRec : allOpps){
            //myWrapperClass wrapRec;
            for(Account parentRec :allAssocaiatedAccounts){
                if(parentRec.Id == childRec.AccountId){
                    myWrapperClass wrapRec = new myWrapperClass();
                    wrapRec.acc = parentRec;
                    wrapRec.opp = childRec;
                    wrapperList.add(wrapRec);
                }
            }

            //Adding Opportunities without account
            if(childRec.AccountId == null){
                    myWrapperClass wrapRec = new myWrapperClass();
                    //wrapRec.acc = null;
                    wrapRec.opp = childRec;
                    wrapperList.add(wrapRec);
            }

        } 
    }



public List<myWrapperClass> wrapperList {get; set;}

public class myWrapperClass{
    public Account acc{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;} 
    public myWrapperClass() { 
         selected = false; 
      } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AccountOpportunity {

public String userid{get;set;}
public list<myWrapperClass>  wrapperList {get;set;}

public AccountOpportunity (){
userid = Userinfo.getUserId();

    fetchData();
}

public void fetchData(){

    //Fetch all associated parents

    ID contactId = [Select contactid from User where id =: Userinfo.getUserid()].contactId;

    ID AccID  = [Select AccountID from Contact where id =: contactid ].AccountId;
    List<Opportunity> allOpps = [Select name,Id,AccountId,Amount from Opportunity Where AccountId =:AccID ];
    wrapperList = new list<myWrapperClass>();
    //For loop to set data
    for(Opportunity childRec : allOpps){

                myWrapperClass wrapRec = new myWrapperClass();
                wrapRec.acc = parentRec;
                wrapRec.opp = childRec;
                wrapperList.add(wrapRec);



    } 
}



public class myWrapperClass{
    public Account acc{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;} 
    public myWrapperClass() { 
         selected = false; 
      } 
}
}
```

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="AccountOpportunity">
   <apex:form>
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrpr">

    <apex:column  value="{!wrpr.acc.Name}"/>
   <apex:column  value="{!wrpr.opp.Name}"/>
   <apex:column  value="{!wrpr.selected}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>  
   <apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

is this you want?